# JQuery |for loop create unique elements classes

Tags: jquery, json, for-loop

I want to loop through my json file  create element to insert information into. Problem is I need to have a unique element defined by something like element class = 'name'[i] i representing a value that will change the class name, (name1, name2, name3 etc...)

If someone could provide me some insight on how to perform this or documentation that helps point me in the right direction it would be appreciated.

```
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
   if (data[i].class = 'IN750')
   {
     //document.createElement("TD")
     //assign unique class (name[i]) 
     //append element by class = name[i]
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you tagged jQuery you can use $.each method to loop through your array, and then use the id to add a class to each element Here's a working solution.

```js
var data = [{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "item 1"
}, {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "item 2"
}, {
    "id": 3,
    "name": "item 3"
}, {
    "id": 4,
    "name": "item 4"
}];

$.each(data, function (i, item) {
    $("#myList").append("<li class='"+item.id+"'>" + item.name + "</li>");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul id="myList"></ul>
```